# Hide a div with opacity animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a div with opacity animate function. Basically, I want the div to be hidden on click. But I want it to fadeout. Below is the code I have for it. can anyone help?

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({ opacity: "0" }, 1000);
  $("div").hide();
});
```

also, is it better to use fadeOut function instead of animate opacity?

Comment: Yes it is better to use the built-in [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function since your code will not wait for the animation to complete before hiding the element. The statements will execute as immediately as possible after each other. To "wait" for the animation to complete requires wiring up a callback function at the end of the animation that then hides the element, which is all taken care of already in the built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fadeOut()` is simpler because it will hide it for you automatically when it is done so you can save that code and it automatically waits for the animation to be done before hiding the element (something your current code was not doing).

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
    [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EXFaN/1/)

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: "0" }, 1000, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

Also you can use `.fadeout(1000)`. to get same behavior.

Comment: Why would you use this instead of `.fadeOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .fadeOut() API for this,

```
$("#div1").click(function() {

   $(this).fadOut(1000);

});
```